# Liferay - client side communication among portlets

Tags: liferay, client-side, portlet

I have a list of portlet projects in eclipse say like 20 (new maybe coming in future or maybe not).

What I wanna do is:

- create a new portlet that will listen to all the button interaction
  on all those 20 or so portlets **and**
- display the result(success or failure) using this portlet that I
  created just now.

I tried looking into IPC but they all have an example where one portlet is firing an event and more than one is listening but I wanna do something vice versa.

How can we achieve this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for client side IPC. So what you need to do is, you can have multiple events bind with the

```
Liferay.fire(eventName, data)
Liferay.on(eventName, function, [scope])
```

Fire events will be fired by the sender portlet, you can have multiple fire events from multiple portlets.
To listen those events you need to have liferay.on, whether in a single portlet or in multiple portlets.
You can put up multiple events in receiver portlet JSP(s) using the below format and sample code

```
Liferay.on('eventName',function(event) {
// write code to get the veluese that sent by sender portlet
});

Example code as follows in receiver portlet view.jsp

Liferay.on('getUserData',function(event) {
 alert('User Name:'+ event.name)
});
```

For further information you can go through the following links. 
http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-client-side-inter-portlet.html
https://www.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-client-side-inter-portlet-communication-using-ajax
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication